# Make my Win'10 accessible from internet but block local network

Tags: local-area-network

I want to give someone rdp or teamviewer access from the internet to a server on my network, but I don't want them to have access to any other pc on the network. What's the easiest way to do this? This is only temporary and is for my home network.

I know I can port-forward port 3389 to that server but when they rdp in they'll be able to access anything on that network. Perhaps just give them Domain User rights and use the built-in windows firewall to Reject all outgoing traffic to the rest of the network? I think there's a better way to make the rest of the network isolated.

Comment: Hi there! It really really depends on how you are connected to internet. Does your Service Provider grants you a reserved ip for you or you share your IP across multiple users in the same neighborhood or even in the same city?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's exactly what a [DMZ (demilitarized zone)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_(computing)) is for. It is a network between your local network (intranet) and the internet, so if a host in the DMZ is compromised, the attacker still cannot access the computers on the intranet (only others in the DMZ).

In your case the "attacker" is a legitimate user of the computer, but the problem remains the same. So you just could take a second router and put your local network router into it along with the computer in question. The second router has to connect to the internet then. The internet for your local network will still work fine (probably double NAT'ed), but the exposed computer cannot pass the inner router.

The other way with the firewall is theoretically possible, but is more pain then help, first configuring it and second being sure to not have forgotten any setting, third not allowing administrator access (because the administrator could just change the firewall rules). DMZ is done fast and is secure.

Comment: Yes correct, if you have another router (which I probably do). The other method is easier and quicker imho. I blocked all local outgoing traffic and the account provided will only be a local user account. This took me 2 mins to do. I just thought there may be a way to configure the pc a DMZ instead of through hardware. Thanks for your help.